# MissingWebPart Health Analyzer Errors

Tags: web-part, health-analyzer

I have a whole bunch of these MissingWebPart errors in my health analyzer, all referring to a web part with GUID baf5274e-a800-8dc3-96d0-0003d9405663. The internet tells me this has to do with a web part in the Search Administration pages and that navigating to these pages will resolve the issue... no luck though. The strange part is that these [MissingWebPart] errors refer to both my SP80 web app's content DB as well as my CA content DB.

Any idea how to fix these?

Answer (score 2):

http://sharepointsoldiers.wordpress.com/2013/04/22/sharepoint-2013missing-serverside-dependencies/

I had the same problem, eventually i did found this that helped me out. It sounds odd but it did the trick.

This thread explains some of it.

"This error will appear on a cleanly installed system in the Health Analyzer Reports until you visit the following pages:

SearchAdministration.aspx
SearchFarmDashboard.aspx
These are: Central Administration, General Application Settings, Farm Search Administration and then Search Service Application."

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/63378c77-7d10-44f6-9a7f-787d0927b1b3/web-part-error-on-a-clean-sp2010-install-in-document-center?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Comment: Been there, tried that. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: I hope you find the answer you are looking for!

Comment: Does this farm have any migrated content or service application databases?